# how to chain CSS animation on different elements

Tags: html, css

**Apply a 1 second transition to the width property of the div one. Apply also a 1 second transition to the width property of the div two, but make sure the animation starts only after the div one has stopped.**

*I am new to CSS , and am finding difficulty in understanding how to sequence this controlled animation. Any help will be great!*

how to connect this animation one after the other !!!

[image]

Comment: pls share html and css code

Comment: Please add your code here, so we can help you with more efficiency but I might sure you have `animation-delay` property in you your second `div`.

Comment: hope this will help you https://css-tricks.com/using-multi-step-animations-transitions/

Comment: What have you tried for your exercise?

Answer (score 1):

Check below

```css
 
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  transition: width 1s;
  -webkit-transition: width 1s; /* Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
  margin-bottom:10px;
}

div.firstDiv:hover {
  width: 300px;
}
div.firstDiv:hover + div {transition-delay:1s;
  width: 300px;
}
div.firstDiv:hover + div + div {transition-delay:2s;
  width: 300px;
}
div.firstDiv:hover + div + div + div {transition-delay:3s;
  width: 300px;
}
div.firstDiv:hover + div + div + div + div {transition-delay:4s;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<h1>The transition Property</h1>

<p>Hover over the div element below, to see the transition effect:</p>

<div class="firstDiv"></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>

<p><b>Note:</b> This example does not work in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: rather than using a div tag directly, it would be rather good to replace it with the class name. But I understood the basics !! thankxx!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `transition: 1s all 1s` for the transition effect and delay, the first value is the duration, the second value is the delay. Then on hover of the first box add the width you want so that both of the boxes will expand.

```css
.box {
  margin: 10px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

.one {
  background-color: red;
  transition: 1s all 0s
}

.two {
  background-color: blue;
  transition: 1s all 1s
}

.one:hover~.two,
.one:hover {
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box one">

</div>

<div class="box two">

</div>
```

Comment: @Peter that should be `.one:hover + .two`, but either way, it will work.

Comment: got it!! so the main thing is that I have to use selectors to connect the elements and manipulate the transactions !! Thanks @little_coder

Comment: the transaction on "two" starts once hover is activated, first a delay is made of 1s and then the actual transaction is started. but the transaction also stops if it remove the hover from "one" before transaction on "one" ends. 

is'nt it that once a transaction is started then it must complete itself ???

Comment: .first:hover + .second   this is true as soon as the hover on first is made, so the transaction has started , with a delay of 1s, right ???   but it dont start once i remove the hover from first!! 

what is the flow of the animation ?? can you please give me a brief !! @little_coder

Comment: @Peter the animation only works when the mouse is hovered on the first element. So, if you remove the hover from the first element, it will cancel the transition effect.

Answer (score 0):

```
.first{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:red;
  transition: width linear 1s;
  -webkit-transition: width linear 1s;
}


.second{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:blue;
  transition: width linear 1s;
  -webkit-transition: width linear 1s;
  transition-delay: 1s;
}

.first:hover{
  width:250px
}
.first:hover + .second{
  width:250px
}
```

Here is the working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shuaibkhan1911/aft5pxv6/20/).

Comment: the transaction on "two" starts once hover is activated, first a delay is made of 1s and then the actual transaction is started. but the transaction also stops if it remove the hover from "one" before transaction on "one" ends. is'nt it that once a transaction is started then it must complete itself ???

Comment: .first:hover + .second   this is true as soon as the hover on first is made, so the transaction has started , with a delay of 1s, right ???   but it dont start once i remove the hover from first!! 

what is the flow of the animation ?? can you please give me a brief !!